# How to fix error : item[_this.props.text_key].split is not a function

Tags: react-native

I'm setting up a new feature for auto-suggestions in my search input and for some words, it gave me an error that says :
"item[_this.props.text_key].split is not a function".

It looks like the API sometimes returning an object, not a string.

This is for a new component that I made for the search suggestions in my TextInput.

```
getSuggestions = async currentSearch => {
    try {
      const response = await Api.serachOutoCompleate(currentSearch)
      let searchAutoComplete = response.suggestions.products.map(product => product.product_title)
      response.suggestions.categories.forEach(categories => searchAutoComplete.push(categories))
      response.suggestions.warehouses.forEach(warehouse => searchAutoComplete.push(warehouse.warehouse_name))
      response.suggestions.upcs.forEach(upcs => searchAutoComplete.push(upcs.product_title))
      response.suggestions.tags.forEach(tags => searchAutoComplete.push(tags.product_title))
      this.storedResults[currentSearch] = response
      if (mounted && currentSearch && searchAutoComplete) this.setState({ currentSearch: currentSearch, searchAutoComplete: searchAutoComplete, response })
      else this.setState({ currentSearch: currentSearch })
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }
```

I expect not to get an error .

Answer (score 0):

> It looks like the API sometimes returning an object, not a string.

So the problem is in the API... please change your question and show the API code.

BUT

If you just want to avoid the error, you can do some checking

```
const splittedName = typeof item[this.props.text_key] === "string" ? item[this.props.text_key].split(' ') : []
```

This will stop the error, but when `item[this.props.text_key]` is an object, you will get an empty array and won't display what you want (because you have no data do display)

What I would do is one of these:

- Fix the API to get always a string
- Do some debugging (you can do a `console.log`) and see what is comming in `item[this.props.text_key]` and do some checking to get what you want.

With only the information you provide, this is the max I can help you.

Comment: I add a new edit to show my API code.
I call "getSuggestions" in the text input...

Comment: That code is ok, but we need to know what is comming in the `response`. Try `console.log` or something like that and then add to your question, please.